# Calling custom method before session auto destroy

Tags: php, session, yii

Is there any way to call a custom method before session gets auto/mannual destroyed?

My problem is, I am capturing user logout time in the DB. Its working fine when user gets logout manually (By calling logout method) but I am not able to capture logout time when user's session gets auto destroyed after timeout.

Appreciate suggestions on this.

Comment: Does the user have to login again after the session is destroyed? i.e. is the session the place where you record the user being logged in? If so them next time they login record the fact that the old login session must have expired?

Answer (score 1):

In php you can implement *SessionHandlerInterface* and use your custom code on **destroy()** or **gc()** (see comments), more info here - http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php

In YII you can setup a [custom session handler](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html#$handler-detail).

Comment: Second link was not parsed properly :-(

Comment: The problem with this is `destroy()`: destroy is only called when the session is explicitly destroyed, not when it's destroyed by the garbage collector. `destroy($sessionId)
    This callback is executed when a session is destroyed with session_destroy() or with session_regenerate_id() with the destroy parameter set to TRUE.`

Comment: Then you need to implement **gc()**.

Comment: Correct. That was pretty much the difference between our answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. [See this website for a in-depth tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/writing-custom-session-handlers)
Using `session_set_save_handler()` ([PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)) you can add your own function for the GC (garbage collection) cycle. That way you can tell which sessions are about to be destroyed by that garbage collection cycle, and manually update those records in the database with the current timestamp.

If you then end your function by calling the default GC handler you've basically inserted your own bit of logic in between.